# 08 Grand Prix Air System question?

Tags: engine

I don't know what this part is called but I need to replace it and I took it into a mechanic[image] and they couldn't order it. Where can I find it?? It is the part in the picture that the intake air temp is going into to.

Comment: You mean the intake tube? Which engine do you have? The 3.8? Try this PN 15219032

Comment: The red arrow is pointing to the vacuum line manifold. Is that the part you are interested in? The black hoses go to the fuel pressure regulator and the one that exits the left side of the photo goes to the EVAP purge solenoid.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the part you are describing might be the outlet duct, the flexible boot and elbow all appear to be one piece

https://www.gmpartsonline.net/auto-parts/2008/pontiac/grand-prix/base-trim/3-8l-v6-gas-engine/engine-cat/air-intake-scat

The part in this link is a little pricey, you might be able to find one in a junk yard. Note that the '06 - '09 Buick Lacrosse uses the same part according to the link.